# How to fix error while creating report (jacoco)

Tags: java, jacoco

I am getting an error while running my blackbox test code. I am using latest 0.8.2 jacoco jars but it throws below errors:

```
    BUILD FAILED
    C:\project\build-continous-integration.xml:71: The following error occurred while executing this line:
    C:\project\build-continous-integration.xml:94: The following error occurred while executing this line:
    C:\project\build-continous-integration.xml:152: Error while creating report
            at org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask.execute(ReportTask.java:501)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
            at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
            at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
            at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:834)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while analyzing 
  project\bc\infra\commands\AbstractCommand.class.
            at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzerError(Analyzer.java:170)
            at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:142)
            at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:165)
            at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:201)
            at org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask.createBundle(ReportTask.java:570)
            at org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask.createReport(ReportTask.java:542)
            at org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask.execute(ReportTask.java:495)
            ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:118)
            at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:140)
            ... 47 more
```

I've checked plenty of topics but most of the issues are about instrumented class but here I do not see this error. Do someone has any idea how to fix it?
If you need more information please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you creating the report? With Maven? Gradle?

Comment: I am using Maven

Comment: I seriously doubt that you use pure Maven, because first line of exception stack trace is `org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

The only known to me case of `Unknown Source` in stack traces from ASM library - is usage of its JARs that do not contain debug information and which [were removed in ASM version 6.0](https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/merge_requests/3). So you're probably using ASM version < 6.0.

However according to presence of module names in your stack trace

```
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

you're using Java >= 9.

ASM versions < 6.0 can not handle Java >= 9 classes and in this case throw exactly  `IllegalArgumentException` at `org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>`.

Furthermore [**JaCoCo 0.8.2 requires usage of ASM 6.2.1**](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html) and depends exactly on this version.

---

```
    at org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask.execute(ReportTask.java:501)
```

for Ant you must use `lib/jacocoant.jar` and not `lib/org.jacoco.ant-0.8.2.201808211720.jar` from JaCoCo distribution, because first one **contains all required dependencies**, while last one does not. According to https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/repo.html it corresponds to artifact from Maven central repository whose `groupId` is `org.jacoco`, `artifactId` is `org.jacoco.ant` and most importantly **`classifier` is `nodeps`**.

Comment: Thanks, it helped however I was getting ant-pom issue when I changed artifactId and added classifier so I skipped this step. Changing to ASM 6.2.1 + jacocoant.jar helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Updating jacoco toolversion to "0.8.7" worked for me.

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.7"
}
```